# Of the 111(+?) invitees to the Biden administration's Summit on Democracy, did any country decline or refuse to participate? If so, any reasons given?

Tags: united-states, international-relations, joe-biden

[This answer to *Did the Biden administration have a working definition of democracy when it chose which countries to invite to its "democracy summit"?*](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/69899/16047) cites US government officials and reports that say that a total of 111 countries were invited to participate the Biden administration's December 2021 Democracy Summit, and for the selection process includes descriptions like:

> ...a stated desire to be "as inclusive as possible" and ensure participation among "a regionally diverse set of well-established and younger democracies whose progress and commitments will advance a more just and peaceful world."

and

> - The United States reached out to a regionally diverse set of well-established and younger democracies whose progress and commitments will advance a more just and peaceful world.
> - Our goal is to be as inclusive as possible. We are working to ensure that all relevant voices and viewpoints feed into the Summit process.

Of the *presently stated* 111 invitees or of any perhaps not so publicly mentioned, did *any country decline or refuse to participate?* If so, were any reasons provided publicly or at least reported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Pakistan and South Africa were invited yet declined to participate. Both countries appear on the State Department's [participant list](https://www.state.gov/participant-list-the-summit-for-democracy/), yet on December 8th, Pakistan's Ministry of Foreign Affairs released the [below statement](https://mofa.gov.pk/press-release-480/):

> We are thankful to the United States for inviting Pakistan for
> participation in the Summit for Democracy, being held virtually on
> 9-10 December 2021.
>
> Pakistan is a large functional democracy with an independent
> judiciary, vibrant civil society, and a free media. We remain deeply
> committed to further deepening democracy, fighting corruption, and
> protecting and promoting human rights of all citizens. In recent
> years, Pakistan has instituted wide-ranging reforms aimed at advancing
> these goals. These reforms have yielded positive results.
>
> We value our partnership with the U.S. which we wish to expand both
> bilaterally as well as in terms of regional and international
> cooperation. We remain in contact with the U.S. on a range of issues
> and believe that we can engage on this subject at an opportune time in
> the future.
>
> Pakistan will, meanwhile, continue to support all efforts aimed
> towards strengthening dialogue, constructive engagement, and
> international cooperation for the advancement of our shared goals.

I don't think South Africa has released an official statement on President Ramaphosa's non-attendance, however the [*Daily Maverick*](https://www.dailymaverick.co.za/article/2021-12-10-ramaphosa-gives-us-presidents-democracy-summit-the-cold-shoulder/) has carried statements from his acting spokesman, Tyrone Seale, as well as International Relations and Cooperation Minister, Naledi Pandor:

> The president’s acting spokesperson, Tyrone Seale, offered the West
> African visit as a reason for the Ramaphosa not attending Biden’s
> summit.
>
> “We are just wrapping up our West Africa visit today. We will not be
> summiting,” he told Daily Maverick.
>
> ...
>
> International Relations and Cooperation Minister Naledi Pandor hinted
> at another reason for declining the invitation, in an interview with
> Daily Maverick journalist Carien du Plessis last Saturday in Accra,
> Ghana.
>
> Pandor said she had received the invitation letter the day before and
> that she was taken aback.
>
> “The letter says things like, ‘America, a country that has always
> supported human rights.’ Really?”
>
> Pandor suggested that perhaps her government declined the invitation
> because it thought a US summit for democracy lacked credibility.